# How to set (*sa_handler)(int) pointer to function which is member of a class? (invalid use of non-static member function)

Tags: c++, linux, pointers

I'm not C++ expert and I'm trying to create a class that handles ctrl+C pressed on terminal.

My methods were working before I started moving them to SignalHandler class.

It looks like I cannot set sigaction.sa_action to:

```
 sigIntHandler.sa_handler = SomeClass->someMethod(int s);
```

like I could in C.

```
sigIntHandler.sa_handler = someMethod(int s);
```

Compiler says:

```
signals.cpp: In constructor ‘SignalHandler::SignalHandler()’:
signals.cpp:5:39: error: invalid use of non-static member function
     registerSignalHandler(ctrlCHandler);
                                       ^
```

**What is wrong with my code?**

I guess I have to convert my class member function to something like this: `(*sa_handler)(int)`.

cpp file:

```
#include "signals.h"

SignalHandler::SignalHandler() {
    isSigtermReceived = false;
    registerSignalHandler(ctrlCHandler);
}

SignalHandler::~SignalHandler() {
}

// private

void SignalHandler::registerSignalHandler(void (*handler)(int)){
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
}

void SignalHandler::ctrlCHandler (int s) { 
    using namespace std;

    cout << endl << "Caught signal " << s << ". Exiting." << endl;
    isSigtermReceived = true;
}
```

h file:

```
#ifndef SIGNALS_H
#define SIGNALS_H

#include <signal.h> // ctrl-c
#include <iostream>

class SignalHandler {
    public:
        SignalHandler();
        virtual ~SignalHandler();
        bool isSigtermReceived;
        void registerSignalHandler(void (*hnd)(int));
    private:
        void ctrlCHandler(int s);
};

#endif /* SIGNALS_H */
```

And this is a struct where I'm trying to assign **sa_handler** field:

```
struct sigaction {
    void     (*sa_handler)(int);
    void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int        sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

Comment: Why not simply using a `std::function` and a lambda expression capturing `this`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: because he's interfacing with C code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a member function to a function pointer.

Despite the actual semantics you can just think that a member function has an hidden `this` reference which can't be passed along as a free function pointer.

The simplest solution is to use a bridge method which will take care of this, eg:

```
class SignalHandlerDispatcher {
private:
  static SignalHandler* _handler;

public:
  static void setHandler(SignalHandler* handler) { _handler = handler; }
  static void sa_handler(int v) { _handler->SomeMethod(v); }
};
```

so that now you can use `SignalHandlerDispatcher::sa_handler` as your callback, since it's `static`.

Comment: OK. I think understand. When I have an object - it has no fixed memory location like in C, so in fact it has no "regular pointer". But I can create static function that can be assigned to sa_handler and calls my member function. Thanks a lot.